# What will be the procedure if I want to change Cipher key for encryption and decryption that I used for Android application database?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, cryptography

I have an android application that has encrypted database. Now I want to change the Cipher key after certain time. So how would I convert the data with previous key to new one?
The amount of data is huge. So I would like to know if there is any efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer depends on your encryption scheme, but most likely there isn't any better way than to decrypt the data using the old key, and then re-encrypt it using the new key.

Since you want to do this on a regular basis, you may want to consider breaking your data into convenient-sized chunks (record, table, etc.), and encrypt each one of those using a random key (different random key for each chunk), then encrypt those chunk keys using a single master key.  To access the data you will have to first fetch and decrypt the chunk key, then use the chunk key to decrypt the actual data.  You may also want to store any IVs that you use together with the chunk keys.  When you want to change the master key, then you decrypt/re-encrypt the chunk keys using the new master key, but you don't have to touch the data (since the chunk key doesn't change).  If you want to change a chunk key, you will have to decrypt/re-encrypt that part of the data, which may not be a problem if you are modifying that data anyway.

And don't forget that when it comes to security, be paranoid - they ARE out to get you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a key indirection. That is create a top level key that encrypts the data encryption key. Then the top level key can be changed and the data encryption key does not need to be changed thus the data does not need to be decrypted and re-encrypted.